# Show the shortcuts when hovering over Microsoft Word icons

Tags: ms-office

I am a fervent keyboardist: how can we find out the shortcuts for these icons? They used to be displayed when you hovered over them, but no more.

This is Microsoft Word for Mac version 16.79

[image: Screenshot of Microsoft Word's Ribbon where the cursor is over an icon that shows its name but does not show the shortcut for it]

Answer (score 0):

Not addressing hovering but how to find shortcuts and set them.

Keyboard shortcut for "Decrease Indent":

- on menu bar Tools - Customize Keyboard
- in "Customize Keyboard" window: in Categories select "Format", in Commands select "DecreaseIndent"
- if there is keyboard shortcut defined already it will be displayed in "Current keys"
- define shortcut in "Press new keyboard shortcut:"

There is also description which can be helpful as command names can be somewhat cryptic.